# Spring boot3.x with EHcache 3.x cacheExpiry not working

Tags: configuration, refresh, ehcache-3, spring-boot-3, cache-expiration

cacheExpiry defined in CacheConfiguration does not stale the cache after defined time.

```
 CacheConfiguration
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(10))) 
here
```

delete operation is not in scope so cannot use evict explicitly.

even after 10 seconds as defined in CacheConfiguration, the cache data didn’t expires.
what can be done to remove specific item from cache after certain duration.?